# Is it important to check if the sensors are supported before reading any values from them?

Tags: android, sensors

I'm developing an application based mainly on the sensors.

I just want to know whether or not it is important to check if the sensor is supported before acquiring values from it? and what is the best way to perform such a check?

For an Example: 
1- should write the following code as a preliminary step before reading any values from the sensor?

2-Is there any better way to make such a check?

**Sample Code**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sensorssystemservice);

    getDefaultSensor();
    if (registerSensors() !=null) ) {
      //....
     //.....
}

private void getDefaultSensor() {
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);        
    mAccelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
           }
private boolean registerSensor() {
     return sm.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

}'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you will eventually get errors as you try to register a listener on a sensor that hasn't been found, but to avoid any issue you indeend would better to check their availability.
That also provides you a "cleaner" code.

When it comes to the method, you could use the getSensorList method : [getSensorList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList%28int%29).

You'd first be able to know if the device owns more than one sensor associated to a certain type, and you could simply check if one of the list elements has the type you require. That check would take you a couple lines.